# SSRS 2008 r2 Report with size 4in*2in is printing in Portrait orientation

Tags: orientation, ssrs-2008-r2, rdl

I have an "rdl" with size as 4in * 2in(orientation as landscape,Margins 0.1in for left ,right ,top & bottom). When we are taking preview that is coming in "Landscape" Orientation.But when we are taking  print out from label printer that is coming in portrait orientation( The label stock is E-CTT400200-3P.  This is a 4 inch x 2 inch label on a roll. ). Also when we are taking print out from normal printer it is coming in "Landscape" Orientation.

Is there any way to print the report in "Landscape"?